# How to properly export Cryptomattes for Photoshop?

Tags: render-passes, cryptomatte

How to properly export Cryptomattes for Photoshop?

Seems I cant find the right thing on the internet so far.

In Modo, was just one click to get the " Color ID Pass"

I've tried EXR multi layer and it doesn't work, I just want a clean ID pass on material/object.

Comment: It's working using exr multilayer. You have to install [exr.io](https://www.exr-io.com/) and setup your passes in the compositor though.

Comment: @brockmann This should be a full answer. Since exr.io adds support for Cryptomatte you wouldn't have to resort to hacky solutions.

Comment: I was looking for a solution to this problem from the very first day since I have switched to Blender 4 years ago. I understand the benefits of Cryptomatte and different ways of usage. But I wanted just one easy pass with material ID with every render, which I can save to PNG and use in Photoshop. In the end, I have made my own addon. If it could help anybody, please enjoy it. https://blendermarket.com/products/cid

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine using OpenEXR multilayer. You just have to install [exr.io for the photoshop side of things](https://www.exr-io.com/) and setup your passes in the compositor using the [cryptomatte node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/matte/cryptomatte.html) and a [file output node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/output/file.html) before rendering.

Comment: warning: do not use any codec when exporting exr multilayer with cryptomatte, even DWAA.
Just set to "none"